# Secuencia php funciona perfectamente en Wamp pero no en servidor externo

Tags: php, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo en mi servidor local con wamp un fichero php donde tengo un código para coger los datos de un formulario y enviarlos al google sheet con una librería de google sheet. Pero cuando llevo estos archivos la libreria y el codigo php al servidor externo de mi web, cuando realizo una prueba la pagina del php se queda en blanco y no funciona ya que no me ingresa los registros al google sheet.

Os dejo el codigo:

```
<?php
// Composer's auto-loading functionality
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest;
use Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory;

$nombreAplicacion = "PhpSheet";
$direccionCorreo = "addrowinsheet@phpsheet.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
$idCliente = "3a5bbd2c9ada9a0f85e8fc1516157400c754d6fa";

// Nombre del SpreadSheet creada
$nombreSpreahSheet = "Php Sheet volcado";
// Nombre de hoja de cálculo
$hojaCalculo = "Hoja 2";

$scope = array('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds');

// Inicializamos Google Client
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName($nombreAplicacion);
$client->setClientId($idCliente);

// credenciales, scope y archivo p12. Agregar el correcto Path al archivo p12
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
$direccionCorreo,
$scope,
file_get_contents('PhpSheet-3a5bbd2c9ada.p12')
);

$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

// si expiro el access token generamos otro
if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
$client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}

// Obtenemos el access token
$obj_token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
$accessToken = $obj_token->access_token;

// Inicializamos google-spreadsheet-client
$serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest($accessToken);
ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);

//Obtenemos los Spreadsheets disponibles para las credenciales actuales
$spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();
$spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets();

// Obtenemos la spreadsheet por su nombre
$spreadsheet = $spreadsheetFeed->getByTitle($nombreSpreahSheet);

// Obtenemos las hojas de cálculo de la spreadsheet obetenida
$worksheetFeed = $spreadsheet->getWorksheets();

// Obtenemos la hoja de cálculo por su nombre
$worksheet = $worksheetFeed->getByTitle($hojaCalculo);
$listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed();


 $dataAgregar = array('nombre' => $_SESSION['nombre'],
 'email' => $_SESSION['email'],
 'telefono' => $_SESSION['phone'],
 'mensaje' => $_SESSION['mensaje'],
 'landing' =>  $landingP
 );
// Agregar datos
$listFeed->insert($dataAgregar);
echo ('Se han insertado correctamente los registros')
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras investigar encontré el problema y la solución.

El problema es que en el servidor donde tengo la web tiene una versión de PHP 5.3 y en wamp server es 5.6, he comprobado en otra web en servidor externo con php 5.6 y el script de php funciona perfectamente. A sí que el error es la versión de php del servidor y la solución es cambiar/actualizar la versión de PHP de 5.3 a 5.6

Comment: Puedes aceptar la respuesta.

Comment: Que respuesta? soy yo el que ha publicado la respuesta y hasta dentro de 2 días no puedo aceptarla

Comment: Bueno, a eso me refería, en 2 dìas entonces, perdón ;)